# Colon after class member declaration?

Tags: c++, struct, syntax

I recently encountered some very strange syntax:

```
struct Test {
    size_t a : 2;
    size_t b : 3;
    size_t c : 4;
};
```

Strangely, this compiles with GCC 4.9.2 with all warning flags turned on.

```
void test_test() {
    Test test;
    std::cout << test.a << " " << test.b << " " << test.c << std::endl;
}
```

While declaring test gives no errors and outputs `0 0 0` (I believe 0 is just coincidental; since the struct is Plain Old Data, none of its members are default initialized to 0), changing
the declaration to a definition via `Test test();` gives the error

```
tester.cpp:14:20: error: request for member 'a' in 'test', which is of non-class
 type 'Test()'
```

Enabling C++11 removes the error messages, but the values still remain enigmatically 0. **What does this syntax achieve**?

Comment: `Test test();` declares a function taking no args and returning `Test`, not a variable of type `Test`.

Comment: (which is called "most vexing parse")

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the clarification; I didn't know that you could declare functions inside functions in C++...

Comment: @deviantfan This explains why we have the `{ }` initialization syntax now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax is bitfields.

```
struct Test {
    size_t a : 2; // Occupies two bits
    size_t b : 3; // Occupies three bits
    size_t c : 4; // Occupies four bits
};
```